# print the distribution in python using dashes

Tags: python

Here's my code right now. So I would like to visualize a normal distribution graph in python only using these dashes (no import)
I am not sure how I should convert the numbers of frequency into dashes. Any ideas? Or any suggestions on the design of my existing codes?

```
normal_list = []  # normally distributed random numbers
for i in range(200000):  # generate 200,000 numbers
    normal_list.append(round(random.normalvariate(10, 7)))  # with mu=10, sigma=7
normal_freq = {}
for i in range(len(normal_freq)):
    if normal_list[i] not in normal_freq:
        normal_freq[normal_list[i]] = 1
    normal_freq[normal_list[i]] += 1

# These codes are for scaling frequency purposes
# avoid too many freq numbers
norm_max = max(normal_freq.values())
norm_min = min(normal_freq.values())
for val, freq in normal_freq.items():
    normal_freq[val] = round((freq - norm_max) * 99 / (norm_max - norm_min) + 100)

for val, freq in normal_freq.items():
    print(val, ': ', freq)
```

```
Here is the desired sample output:
1: ---​
2: --------​
4: -----------​
7: -------​
8: --​
11: -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print statement should be something like `print("%d: %s" % (val, '-' * freq) )`.

The magic is in the `'-' * freq` expression; what this does is print out `freq` dashes (e.g. if `freq == 3`, then you get `---`.

Edit: See BeRT2me's comment below if what I wrote is a little unreadable.

Comment: Alternative formatting that may be easier to read: `print(f"{val}: {'-' * freq}")`

Comment: @BeRT2me That's fair. I used C/C++ all through college, and so I'm used to the C-style format specifiers.